# BibTeX "1. No Title" Reference?

Tags: bibliographies

I am having a strange error with my bibliography. Notice the first reference  in the attached screen-shot (number 1). It says "No title". Moreover, if I search for the reference all over the PDF file that results from pdflatex, reference 1 is not cited anywhere so I cannot figure out which reference is wrong in the bib file (I have a huge bib file from Mendeley, so manual analysis is not an option...)

Can anyone shed any light on this?

[image: Error in bibliography]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you search your bib file for an entry with author named "No Title"?

Comment: @Mico Thanksssss you just saved my ass over here! Such a basic mistake :D Post this as an answer and ill accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the mystery entry seems to be "authored" by a person with name `No Title`, can you search your bib file for an entry with field `author = "No Title"` or `author = {No Title}`? Once the entry is found, you can either delete it outright or fix it up, e.g., by correcting the `author` field.